# How to translate this python to Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell and as an exercise I'm trying to convert write the read_from function following code to Haskell. Taken from Peter Norvig's Scheme interpreter.
Is there a straightforward way do this?

```python
def read(s):
    "Read a Scheme expression from a string."
    return read_from(tokenize(s))

parse = read

def tokenize(s):
    "Convert a string into a list of tokens."
    return s.replace('(',' ( ').replace(')',' ) ').split()

def read_from(tokens):
    "Read an expression from a sequence of tokens."
    if len(tokens) == 0:
        raise SyntaxError('unexpected EOF while reading')
    token = tokens.pop(0)
    if '(' == token:
        L = []
        while tokens[0] != ')':
            L.append(read_from(tokens))
        tokens.pop(0) # pop off ')'
        return L
    elif ')' == token:
        raise SyntaxError('unexpected )')
    else:
        return atom(token)

def atom(token):
    "Numbers become numbers; every other token is a symbol."
    try: return int(token)
    except ValueError:
        try: return float(token)
        except ValueError:
            return Symbol(token)
```

Comment: You might want to look at [Write Yourself a Scheme in 24 Hours](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours/Parsing) if you want to take this project further.

Comment: +1 I have been looking for a good excuse to blog about exactly this. I guess I'll just write it up as a SO answer instead.

Comment: As AndrewC recommended, I think it is more natural to do this in Haskell using parser combinators. I highly recommend reading through that tutorial. Monad transformers are great, but not necessary to do this in Haskell.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Haskell, you wouldn't use an algorithm that mutates the data it operates on. So no, there is no straightforward way to do that. However, the code can be rewritten using recursion to avoid updating variables. Solution below uses the [MissingH](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MissingH) package because Haskell annoyingly doesn't have a `replace` function that works on strings.

```
import Data.String.Utils (replace)
import Data.Tree  
import System.Environment (getArgs)

data Atom = Sym String | NInt Int | NDouble Double | Para deriving (Eq, Show)

type ParserStack = (Tree Atom, Tree Atom)

tokenize = words . replace "(" " ( " . replace ")" " ) " 

atom :: String -> Atom
atom tok =
  case reads tok :: [(Int, String)] of
    [(int, _)] -> NInt int
    _ -> case reads tok :: [(Double, String)] of
      [(dbl, _)] -> NDouble dbl
      _ -> Sym tok

empty = Node $ Sym "dummy"
para = Node Para

parseToken (Node _ stack, Node _ out) "(" =
  (empty $ stack ++ [empty out], empty [])
parseToken (Node _ stack, Node _ out) ")" =
  (empty $ init stack, empty $ (subForest (last stack)) ++ [para out])
parseToken (stack, Node _ out) tok =
  (stack, empty $ out ++ [Node (atom tok) []])

main = do
  (file:_) <- getArgs
  contents <- readFile file
  let tokens = tokenize contents
      parseStack = foldl parseToken (empty [], empty []) tokens
      schemeTree = head $ subForest $ snd parseStack
  putStrLn $ drawTree $ fmap show schemeTree
```

`foldl` is the haskeller's basic structured recursion tool and it serves the same purpose as your while loop and recursive call to `read_from`. I think the code can be improved a lot, but I'm not so used to Haskell. Below is an almost straight transliteration of the above to Python:

```python
from pprint import pprint
from sys import argv

def atom(tok):
    try:
        return 'int', int(tok)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            return 'float', float(tok)
        except ValueError:
            return 'sym', tok

def tokenize(s):
    return s.replace('(',' ( ').replace(')',' ) ').split()

def handle_tok((stack, out), tok):
    if tok == '(':
        return stack + [out], []
    if tok == ')':
        return stack[:-1], stack[-1] + [out] 
    return stack, out + [atom(tok)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tokens = tokenize(open(argv[1]).read())
    tree = reduce(handle_tok, tokens, ([], []))[1][0]
    pprint(tree)
```

Answer (score 56):

There is a straightforward way to "transliterate" Python into Haskell. This can be done by clever usage of monad transformers, which sounds scary, but it's really not. You see, due to purity, in Haskell when you want to use effects such as mutable state (e.g. the `append` and `pop` operations are performing mutation) or exceptions, you have to make it a little more explicit. Let's start at the top.

```
parse :: String -> SchemeExpr
parse s = readFrom (tokenize s)
```

The Python docstring said "Read a Scheme expression from a string", so I just took the liberty of encoding this as the type signature (`String -> SchemeExpr`). That docstring becomes obsolete because the type conveys the same information. Now... what *is* a `SchemeExpr`? According to your code, a scheme expression can be an int, float, symbol, or list of scheme expressions. Let's create a data type that represents these options.

```
data SchemeExpr
  = SInt    Int
  | SFloat  Float
  | SSymbol String
  | SList   [SchemeExpr]
  deriving (Eq, Show)
```

In order to tell Haskell that the `Int` we are dealing with should be treated as a `SchemeExpr`, we need to tag it with `SInt`. Likewise with the other possibilities. Let's move on to `tokenize`.

```
tokenize :: String -> [Token]
```

Again, the docstring turns into a type signature: turn a `String` into a list of `Token`s. Well, what's a Token? If you look at the code, you'll notice that the left and right paren characters are apparently special tokens, which signal particular behaviors. Anything else is... unspecial. While we *could* create a data type to more clearly distinguish parens from other tokens, let's just use Strings, to stick a little closer to the original Python code.

```
type Token = String
```

Now let's try writing `tokenize`. First, let's write a quick little operator for making function chaining look a bit more like Python. In Haskell, you can define your own operators.

```
(|>) :: a -> (a -> b) -> b
x |> f = f x

tokenize s = s |> replace "(" " ( "
               |> replace ")" " ) "
               |> words
```

`words` is Haskell's version of `split`. However, Haskell has no pre-cooked version of `replace` that I know of. Here's one that should do the trick:

```
-- add imports to top of file
import Data.List.Split (splitOn)
import Data.List (intercalate)

replace :: String -> String -> String -> String
replace old new s = s |> splitOn old
                      |> intercalate new
```

If you read the docs for `splitOn` and `intercalate`, this simple algorithm should make perfect sense. Haskellers would typically write this as `replace old new = intercalate new . splitOn old`, but I used `|>` here for easier Python audience understanding.

Note that `replace` takes three arguments, but above I only invoked it with two. In Haskell you can partially apply any function, which is pretty neat. `|>` works sort of like the unix pipe, if you couldn't tell, except with more type safety.

---

Still with me? Let's skip over to `atom`. That nested logic is a bit ugly, so let's try a slightly different approach to clean it up. We'll use the `Either` type for a much nicer presentation.

```
atom :: Token -> SchemeExpr
atom s = Left s |> tryReadInto SInt
                |> tryReadInto SFloat
                |> orElse (SSymbol s)
```

Haskell doesn't have the automagical coersion functions `int` and `float`, so instead we will build `tryReadInto`. Here's how it works: we're going to thread `Either` values around. An `Either` value is either a `Left` or a `Right`. Conventionally, `Left` is used to signal error or failure, while `Right` signals success or completion. In Haskell, to simulate the Python-esque function call chaining, you just place the "self" argument as the last one.

```
tryReadInto :: Read a => (a -> b) -> Either String b -> Either String b
tryReadInto f (Right x) = Right x
tryReadInto f (Left s) = case readMay s of
  Just x -> Right (f x)
  Nothing -> Left s

orElse :: a -> Either err a -> a
orElse a (Left _) = a
orElse _ (Right a) = a
```

`tryReadInto` relies on type inference in order to determine which type it is trying to parse the string into. If the parse fails, it simply reproduces the same string in the `Left` position. If it succeeds, then it performs whatever function is desired and places the result in the `Right` position. `orElse` allows us to eliminate the `Either` by supplying a value in case the former computations failed. Can you see how `Either` acts as a replacement for exceptions here? Since the `ValueException`s in the Python code are *always caught* inside the function itself, we know that `atom` will never *raise* an exception. Similarly, in the Haskell code, even though we used `Either` on the inside of the function, the interface that we expose is pure: `Token -> SchemeExpr`, no outwardly-visible side effects.

---

OK, let's move on to `read_from`. First, ask yourself the question: what side effects does this function have? It mutates its argument `tokens` via `pop`, and it has internal mutation on the list named `L`. It also raises the `SyntaxError` exception. At this point, most Haskellers will be throwing up their hands saying "oh noes! side effects! gross!" But the truth is that Haskellers use side effects all the time as well. We just call them "monads" in order to scare people away and avoid success at all costs. Mutation can be accomplished with the `State` monad, and exceptions with the `Either` monad (surprise!). We will want to use both at the same time, so we'll in fact use "monad transformers", which I'll explain in a bit. It's not *that* scary, once you learn to see past the cruft.

First, a few utilities. These are just some simple plumbing operations. `raise` will let us "raise exceptions" as in Python, and `whileM` will let us write a while loop as in Python. For the latter, we simply have to make it explicit in what order the effects should happen: first perform the effect to compute the condition, then if it's `True`, perform the effects of the body and loop again.

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.State
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class (lift)

raise = lift . Left

whileM :: Monad m => m Bool -> m () -> m ()
whileM mb m = do
  b <- mb
  if b
  then m >> whileM mb m
  else return ()
```

We again want to expose a pure interface. However, there is a chance that there will be a `SyntaxError`, so we will indicate in the type signature that the result will be *either* a `SchemeExpr` or a `SyntaxError`. This is reminiscent of how in Java you can annotate which exceptions a method will raise. Note that the type signature of `parse` has to change as well, since it might raise the SyntaxError.

```
data SyntaxError = SyntaxError String
                 deriving (Show)

parse :: String -> Either SyntaxError SchemeExpr

readFrom :: [Token] -> Either SyntaxError SchemeExpr
readFrom = evalStateT readFrom'
```

We are going to perform a stateful computation on the token list that is passed in. Unlike the Python, however, we are not going to be rude to the caller and mutate the very list passed to us. Instead, we will establish our own state space and initialize it to the token list we are given. We will use `do` notation, which provides syntactic sugar to make it look like we're programming imperatively. The `StateT` monad transformer gives us the `get`, `put`, and `modify` state operations.

```
readFrom' :: StateT [Token] (Either SyntaxError) SchemeExpr
readFrom' = do
  tokens <- get
  case tokens of
    [] -> raise (SyntaxError "unexpected EOF while reading")
    (token:tokens') -> do
      put tokens' -- here we overwrite the state with the "rest" of the tokens
      case token of
        "(" -> (SList . reverse) `fmap` execStateT readWithList []
        ")" -> raise (SyntaxError "unexpected close paren")
        _   -> return (atom token)
```

I've broken out the `readWithList` portion into a separate chunk of code,
because I want you to see the type signature. This portion of code introduces
a *new scope*, so we simply layer another `StateT` on top of the monad stack
that we had before. Now, the `get`, `put`, and `modify` operations refer
to the thing called `L` in the Python code. If we want to perform these operations
on the `tokens`, then we can simply preface the operation with `lift` in order
to strip away one layer of the monad stack.

```
readWithList :: StateT [SchemeExpr] (StateT [Token] (Either SyntaxError)) ()
readWithList = do
  whileM ((\toks -> toks !! 0 /= ")") `fmap` lift get) $ do
    innerExpr <- lift readFrom'
    modify (innerExpr:)
  lift $ modify (drop 1) -- this seems to be missing from the Python
```

In Haskell, appending to the end of a list is inefficient, so I instead prepended, and then reversed the list afterwards. If you are interested in performance, then there are better list-like data structures you can use.

Here is the complete file: http://hpaste.org/77852

---

So if you're new to Haskell, then this probably looks terrifying. My advice is to just give it some time. The Monad abstraction is not nearly as scary as people make it out to be. You just have to learn that what most languages have baked in (mutation, exceptions, etc), Haskell instead provides via libraries. In Haskell, you must explicitly specify which effects you want, and controlling those effects is a little less convenient. In exchange, however, Haskell provides more safety so you don't accidentally mix up the wrong effects, and more power, because you are in complete control of how to combine and refactor effects.

Comment: If you're going to mix the `Either` and `State` monads, that is basically one variation on the `Parser` monad:  `newtype Parser a = Parser { runParser :: String -> Either ErrorMessage (String,  a) }`, which is exactly equivalent to `StateT String (Either ErrorMessage) a`.  Moreover, it fits exactly what he's doing: parsing.  If you just define a monad instance for that then you don't need to introduce monad transformers.

Comment: Alternatively, you can do `newtype Parser a = Parser { runParser :: StateT String (Either ErrorMessage) a } deriving (Monad)` and get all the machinery for free.

Comment: The point I want to drive home here is that Haskell provides common imperative language features as libraries. Want mutation? Use State. Want exceptions? Use Either. Want reinversion of control? Use Cont. New Haskellers should learn how to recognize and use the appropriate tool, so I felt it best to illustrate each one separately.

Comment: This is brilliant code and terrible advice for a beginner on how to implement this functionality in idiomatic Haskell. :D

Comment: @HeinrichApfelmus indeed, my goal here was not idiomatic Haskell. Rather, it was (as far as is possible in Haskell) to be Pythonic.

Comment: Since posting the question back in mid November I have been studying Haskell. I recently looked at your answer again and am now able to appreciate it. So I wanted to say thanks for taking the time to give such a detailed and insightful response.